# Using two salts - one stored with the password, one stored in a random row in a separate table

Tags: authentication, salt, sha256

Imagine a login system is being created, and a user's password is hashed thusly:

```
Users.password = PBKDF2(salt1 + password + salt2)
```

The result of that ^ operation and `salt1` are stored side-by-side in the same table, let's say `Users`.

`salt2`, however, is stored in a random row in a separate table called `UnorderedSalts`.

When a user attempts to login, the system checks their credentials by computing:

```
for (let i = 0; i < UnorderedSalts.length; i++)
  if (PBKDF2(Users.salt1 + input.password + UnorderedSalts[i]) === Users.password)
    return true; // Match found!

return false; // No matches were found
```

Since `salt2` is not stored on the same row as `salt` and `password`, the computation must be repeated potentially many times before a match is found, depending on how many users are setup.

My question is this:

- Would this make for a more secure system, by increasing the potential compute time?
- Does this compromise the security of the password?
- Or, is there no benefit at all?

Comment: If you want to increase the hash difficulty, why not just increase the hash difficulty instead of doing this somewhat convoluted method?  Typically you use something like bcrypt or pbkdf, or simply just iterate your hashes recursively many thousands of times, which is all bcrypt/pbkdf does.  Your approach has the disadvantage of only increasing security when the number of users increases, and may in fact get TOO hard if you have enough users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that "increasing the potential computation time" is good for security. That is the very basis for password hashing - slow is good!

But this is an awfully inconvenient way to make the hashing slow! For some passwords, an attacker will get lucky and crack them fast if they happened to try the right salt early. There is a risk that database files, logs or similar will leak the order hashes were created and thus give clues to what salt is linked to what account. If your site is a success, and you suddenly get a hundred times as many users, your servers will be overloaded when they have a hundred times more hashes to compute. It will be a mess.

All modern, good password hashing functions, including PBKDF2, bcrypt and scrypt, comes with built-in methods to configure the computation time. These parameters are known as "cost factors". Use them instead! It will give you a much simpler and cleaner architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no benefit at all.

To answer your most immediate question, the second salt does not provide any benefits beyond the ones already provided by the first salt. At most, you gain a miniscule amount of security-through-obscurity by splitting the hash up into non-obvious places, but obscurity buys, at most, a few minutes while the attacker looks at your system more closely.  At worst, security-through-obscurity makes developers and administrators *feel* more secure, which reduces the chances that they'll implement *effective* security.

Security through obscurity goes directly against [Kerckhoff's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle), which I like to borrow Shannon's reformulation: "The enemy knows the system."

However, that's not the only reason why there is no benefit at all.

**Simply salting and hashing passwords is no longer considered a secure way to store passwords.**

You want to use a key-stretching algorithm with tunable cost factors.

The current standard on password management, [NIST 800-63B](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html), lists PBKDF2 and BALLOON, however the current key-stretching algorithms suggested by security professionals are KDFs based on bcrypt, scrypt, or Argon2.

PBKDF2 will certainly work in a pinch, when you don't have the latest libraries available -- Just make sure that the library you're using is generating an actual HMAC at the end of each round, as many naive implementations will use the hash result itself as input to the next round.

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to the length of your `UnorderedSalts.length`: if it's too low (perhaps 10) then you add very little security; if it's too high, you're now in a position where every single user login attempt requires a large chunk of CPU power to validate.

Ideally you want to be able to authenticate the user/password combination in as few steps as possible, while still making it hard for attackers to brute-force the system.

But in your suggestion you'll require somewhere between 0 and `UnorderedSalts.length` to validate the password. This is a performance nightmare that includes not just additional compute, but additional round-trips to/from your database to pick up these unordered salts. Not to mention the complexity introduced by the sheer abnormality of this approach.

If bruteforcing the passwords is your primary threat, the way to address it is (as mentioned in the previous answer) using an algorithm whose difficulty can be fine-tuned. By just increasing the difficulty factor, we can slow down attackers by 2x, 4x even 128x -- and all this is pure CPU compute without DB lookups.